# Ingress and Helm Chart HTTPS issue

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes, wso2, cluster-computing, kubernetes-helm

subject refers, i am trying to configure the below with both HTTP and HTTPS redirection from ingress controller to WSO2 Tomcat container 
https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-is

HTTP is working fine and not HTTPS so i suspect some of the configuration or the RSA certificate installed incorrectly.

Q1) How to check the HTTPS connection from the LOG file from both ingress proxy level and tomcat level. Say, when i use browser to hit the URL, i can suppose able to see the logging or error from the printing from the LOG file.

Q2) From both ingress proxy and tomcat log file during "startup", what is the logging that the indicate the HTTPS services is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can find logs for your ingress in pod `nginx-ingress-controller-somehash`

You can check ingress-controller logs here:
`kubectl log nginx-ingress-controller-somehash`

As I see you run tomcat inside kubernetes so tomcat log you can find:
`kubectl log tomcat-podname`

You may found some errors or warnings that's should be the marker of work